# break bibliography in a textblock (beamer)

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, page-breaking

In `beamer`, I have a background figure in my bibliography frame. I have to put bibliography in a `textblock` to locate it correctly (wtr the background figure). I also want to allow frame break, but `allowframebreaks` doesn't work with `textblock`:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,xcolor=table]{beamer}
   \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
    \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
    \setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}        
    \begin{frame}{main}
       ciao~\cite{Aochi_et_al_2013}~\cite{Gatti_et_al_2015}~\cite{Smerzini_et_al_2016}~\cite{Argyroudis_et_al_2014}
    \end{frame}
        {
            \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{github_logo_flag.png}}
            \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
                \bibliographystyle{plain}
                \begin{textblock}{70}(55,95)
                    \tiny\bibliography{MyCollection1.bib}
                \end{textblock}
            \end{frame}
        }
    \end{document}
```

[image]
My bib file (MyCollection1.bib) is the following

```
% Encoding: ISO-8859-1

@Article{Aochi_et_al_2013a,
  Title                    = {{Finite difference simulations of seismic wave propagation for the 2007 Mw 6.6 Niigata-ken Chuetsu-Oki earthquake: Validity of models and reliable input ground motion in the near field}},
  Author                   = {Aochi, H. and Ducellier, A. and Dupros, F. and Delatre, M. and Ulrich, T. and {de Martin}, F. and Yoshimi, M.},
  Journal                  = {Pure and Applied Geophysics},
  Year                     = {2013},
  Note                     = {Springer Verlag (Germany)},
  Number                   = {(1-2)},
  Pages                    = {43-64},
  Volume                   = {170},

  Doi                      = {10.1007/s00024-011-0429-5},
  Institution              = {hal-00980238},
  ISBN                     = {0002401104295},
  ISSN                     = {00334553},
  Publisher                = {Springer Verlag (Germany)},
  Url                      = {https://hal-brgm.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00980238}
}

@InProceedings{Argyroudis_et_al_2014,
    Title                    = {{Seismic fragility curves of shallow tunnels considering SSI and aging effects}},
    Author                   = {Argyroudis, S and Tsinidis, G and Gatti, F and Pitilakis, K},
    Booktitle                = {2\textsuperscript{nd} Eastern European Tunnelling Conference},
    Year                     = {2014},
    Pages                    = {1-10},
    Keywords                 = {fragility analysis,lining corrosion,seismic risk assessment}
}

@InProceedings{Gatti_et_al_2015,
    author    = {Gatti, Filippo and Lopez-Caballero, Fernando and Clouteau, Didier},
    title     = {{One-Dimensional Seismic Soil Response at the Nuclear Power Plant of Kashiwazaki-Kariwa during the 2007~{N}iigata-Chuetsu-Oki Earthquake}},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the Fifteenth International Conference on Civil, Structural and Environmental Engineering Computing},
    year      = {2015},
    editor    = {Kruis, J. and Tsompanakis, Y. and Topping, B.H.V.},
    number    = {157},
    pages     = {1-16},
    address   = {Stirlingshire, UK,},
    publisher = {Civil-Comp Press},
    doi       = {10.4203/ccp.108.157},
    isbn      = {0123456789},
    issn      = {1759-3433},
    keywords  = {behaviour,kashiwazaki-kariwa,near field effects,nonlinear be-,polarization,strong motions},
}

@Misc{Smerzini_et_al_2016,
    author    = {Smerzini, C. and Gatti, F. and Paolucci, R.},
    title     = {{An artificial neural network approach to support physics-based generation of broadband earthquake ground motions}},
    month     = {Septembre},
    year      = {2016},
    address   = {Trieste, IT},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 35\textsuperscript{th} General Assembly of the European Seismological Commission},
    number    = {707},
}
```

Comment: Can you please make a compilable MWE? [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Answer (score 2):

The placement of your image looks as if the text just has to be moved down. If this is not enough, I would rather modify the margins of the frame to restrict the text area, then trying to break some environment over slides.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}  

{
    \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{github}}
    \addtolength{\headsep}{2cm}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
      \nocite{*}
      \bibliographystyle{plain}
      \tiny\bibliography{test.bib}
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]